# XeLatex and PStricks on Mac OSX

Tags: xetex, pstricks, texshop

I just tried to compile the following with XeLaTeX in TeXShop:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatexmk
% mwe.tex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot}
\begin{document}
%
\psframebox[framesep=0]{
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-0.5)(1.5,1)
 \psaxes[labels=none]{->}(0,0)(-1,-0.5)(1.5,1)
\end{pspicture}}
%
\end{document}
```

but at the end I got the following error message:

```
..
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: Permission denied
Current file position is 69
GPL Ghostscript 9.53.3: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
)
```

and the PDF is empty. The same happens if I am running `XeLaTeX` in a terminal. I checked the net and found some hints from 2016 or 2019 but they are all not understandable to me.

If I do: `latex mwe -> drips mwe` I get a mwe.ps file. Now if in the finder I open this file, it will be converted into the mwe.pdf file with the expected diagram.

XeLaTeX at the prompt gives:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=xelatex)
```

OS X: 11.2.3
TeXShop: 4.64

Ulrich

Comment: Did you run xelatex with  the `--shell-escape` switch?

Comment: But --shell-escape has to do with PdfLaTeX? I tried, but no other behavior, i.e. it seem the programm gs (Ghostscript) causes the failure.

Comment: As Herb mentions below Ghostscript (which is needed here to process the generated ps data) has been updated and now requires extra options for transparency to work. As far as I know transparency is used a lot in pstricks. If I'm not mistaken there are other questions about this and it might come down to extra options for xdvipdfm

Answer (score 1):

Ghostscript 9.53.x needs a special couple of parameters to process that. What front end are you using? If a recent TeXShop (4.64 is the latest) go to `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/Inactive/GhostscriptTransparencyEngines` and read the example document there to install the latexTRmk and xelatexTRmk engines. Then use the xelatexTRmk engine instead of the xelatexmk engine and the file should compile fine. PS: You can use the `TeXShop->Open ~/Library/TeXShop` menu item to get started. PPS: you need to restart TeXShop for the newly activated engines to be seen by TeXShop.

Comment: 1. xelatexTR is working 
2. latexTR is working
3. xelatexTRmk and latexTRmk and are not working: Message: xelatexTRmkrcl does not exist

I have the version 4.64 and I am wondering, why natively the xelatex command is not working out of the box.

From the READ-ME.tex: " .. Instructions about where to place the 
three files are enclosed.." but no further information about this.

Comment: @Ulrich: There are two files in a sub-folder of `GhostscriptTransparencyEngines` that must be copied to `~/Library/TeXShop/bin/tslatexmk`. Once those are copied latexTRmk and xelatexTRmk will work properly.

Comment: Please tell me, which one? I am completely lost.

Comment: OK OK , I got it. 
Question: Why is this not the default of TeXShop?

Comment: Not everyone using TeXShop has a recent Ghostscript. That’s probably why it isn’t the default for xelatex itself.

Comment: OK, I understood. But I've searched and haven't found how to do it. Not even in the documentation on TeXShop (maybe I overlooked it). But a hint there would be appropriate? Anyway, I got it and .. (Thank you seems forbidden here)

Comment: @Ulrich : I’ll try to add better documentation.

Comment: the documentation is ok. Just a small hint is enough. Thanks for the support.

Comment: @Ulrich : There are two additional files (in the `For TeXShop/bin/tslatexmk` folder) that need to be added as the folder name implies for the `mk` version of the transparency engines to wortk properly.

Answer (score 0):

In the file `/...tex-distro.../dvipdfmx/dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg`. you'll find only *one* important line and some documentation how to use this file with `xe(La)tex`. This important line starts with:

```
D  "rungs -q -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY -dNOSAFER ...
```

In the main config file `dvipdfmx.cfg` (in the same directory) you'll find a similar line which you should replace with the above one.

Ghostscript changed its behaviour and allows by default no transparency and no running external files. Both are the default for PSTricks files.

Answer (score 0):

I was unsatisfied with the above solution to change dvipdfmx.cfg, as this file is supposed to be managed by the package manager. However, it turns out that you can get xelatex to use the packaged `dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg` by using `-output-driver`:

```
xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -i dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg -q -E" ...
```

This resolves issues with pstricks for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue. In the terminal, what Chris Down suggests does indeed work: I can compile and it produces the PDF I want. But it doesn't work through TeXShop: I edited the TeXShop preferences, checked the path and modified Engine>TeX+dvips+distiller, putting

```
xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -i dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg -q -E"
```

but when I compile through TeXShop, with the XeLaTeX composer, it seems to work fine at first (and it produces exactly the same .log and .aux), but it doesn't produce the right pdf, with the same error as Ulrich reports (/invalidfaccess in --run-- called by pstricks.pro).

I don't understand what to put in TeXShop preferences for it to actually do exactly the same thing as the terminal does, no more, no less...

Thanks, best regards, Christian (it's for a friend, I personally use emacs and the terminal on my mac).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your question will mit be read by mañy people Here, pleased ASK a New one